# How to use letter/number combinations in pygame, event.key?

Tags: pygame

I know that in pygame, for the command:

```
if event.key==K_r:
```

That when you press the letter r on the keyboard you get a response. But I would like to increase the complexity to a letter/number combination for a jukebox. So I tried:

```
if event.key==K_r3:
```

And I pressed r then I pressed 3. But I get an error: name 'K_r3' is not defined. I'm hoping I don't have to write out a definition for each possible letter/number combination. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Don't fret Rico, there is an answer. Try the following:

`if event.type == KEYDOWN:`

`#this says that a key was pressed down`

`keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()`

`#this is a list of all the keys that were pressed down. now, if you want to do do multiple keys, the answer is as follows:`

`if keys[K_3] and keys[K_r]:`

`(function)`

I hope this helps you on your quest to pygame greatness.